# storing () in a variable of unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Any idea how to store the speacial characters open and close braces ( ) in a variable that is used in the unix shell script

Comment: Are you using BASH or SH? If you're using BASH, `()` will work fine, however, if you're using SH, you should be using backticks to make it POSIX compliant.

Comment: It's not clear that OP is referring to command substitution. If he is, `$(...)` is also POSIX-compliant. POSIX is not limited to what the original Bourne shell supported; if I recall, it's mostly based on `ksh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
#!/bin/sh
asdf="()"
echo $asdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use quotes around your parenthesis:

```
$ x='()' 

$ echo $x
()
```